# Problems with multiple SMS at one click using

Tags: php, loops, sms

Is there anybody who could help with php loop? 
I want to send multiple sms in once.

here is my code:

```
<?php 
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
'http' => array( 
    'timeout' => 1 
    ) 
) 
); 
$from = $_POST["f"];
$too = $_POST["t"];
$text = urlencode($_POST['m']);
file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/api/sendSms.php?apiKey=xxxxxxx&charset=UTF-8&senderId=$from&mobile=$too&message=$text", 0, $ctx); 
?>
```

Comment: Means, Same message on multiple numbers?

Comment: yes please. i just don't know what to do

Comment: you just need to put your last line in the loop. Using foreach.

Comment: @Irfan Do  u have some way out ?

Comment: could u please do that? i sucks in coding :/

Comment: check my answer is it usable?

Comment: I'm sorry but i did not worked ;/

Comment: add some mobile numbers manually into array then check

Comment: no respons.....

Comment: OMG ITS WORKING SOOO GOOD <3

Comment: thankyou soo much brother :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have an array that having mobile numbers.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
'http' => array( 
    'timeout' => 1 
    ) 
) 
); 
$from = $_POST["f"];
$too = explode(',',$_POST["t"]);  // array should be like [65882522,3366666,885555855]
$text = urlencode($_POST['m']);

foreach($too as $to ) {
    file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/api/sendSms.php?apiKey=xxxxxxx&charset=UTF-8&senderId=$from&mobile=$to&message=$text", 0, $ctx);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try it now :D

Comment: I'm using this code and posting to the form, input. and action="index.php" and its working good with one number

Comment: Thanks so much @Irfan it's working soooo good. i never tought that it's posible ;)